# Can Selenium Find the correct Web Element on a responsive, resized website?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, responsive-design, webdriver

My web application is responsive. I.e. it resizes for different screen sizes. Our developers have coded for this, and as a result, most web elements found by xpath actually have 2. One of them for full screen and one for "mobile" or small screen.

For example, if I use Firepath to search for the Xpath by just link text, it will say "2 elements found" Only one can be seen, then if I resize the browser window, that one disappears and the other one can be seen.

My question is: Can I use one Selenium script for both screen size? It would automatically use whichever element is visible or is clickable? If I script for just one of the two elements, I'll get "Element is not clickable" exception.

Or s the best solution to add all of the mobile elements to the page object separately, and create my methods something like:

```
if (DesktopWebElement.isVisible)
    do the test for desktop
else if (MobileWebElement.isVisible)
    do the test for mobile
```

It seems like quite a bit of extra work to add every mobile element separately and script every method in the page object like this. In the interest of saving time, I was just wondering if there's a way I could use an Xpath that finds both elements, and Selenium will find the first one that is visible.

Comment: I've seen a strategy to dynamically load `maps` (basically a class containing selectors) for page objects based on the client being used. Sounds like this is a similar scenario where the functionality is the same, but the locators are slightly different. It was tricky, but essentially a `PagesFactory` was used to create new `PageObjects`, and that page factory would figure out which map to use for it based on some property. If you can have your selectors be mobile or desktop specific you could do something similar... but it wasn't simple

Answer (score 0):

I have the situations where the columns that get displayed vary by screen size in addition to different buttons.

My page files contain methods like

```
public int getScreenWidth() {
    Dimension aScreen = webDriver.manage().window().getSize();
    return aScreen.getWidth();
}
```

Then my code has things like:

```
if (screenWidth < 1440 ) {
    ...
}
```

Developers worked out with the business which columns dropped and at which widths.

There are screen width cutoff values set by the developers that determine which button gets displayed.  So I click on the desktop or mobile button depending on the current screen width.  Ask development to document the screen width cutoff values that they coded.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocatedBy`, as per [documents](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) it would give you a visible element attached to the DOM. This would give you ability to just interact with the element that is visible our of the two

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocatedBy(By.xpath(".//someXpath")));
element.click();
```

You can also try [elementTobeClickable](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) condition if that suits you better. Note that this is NOT going to slow your tests down, as soon as the element is visible/clickable it will be returned.